# Why am I getting this load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019 error

Tags: docker

I have trying to install hadoop using docker on windows 10 platform. When running this command I got the following error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vdGw.png)

I unchecked the Use Docker Compose V2 option in docker settings but still did not work for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.